# Cannot delete child in one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

When I put `inverse=true` into `set`, nothing gets deleted. When I don't, and I remove `MealIngredient` from `set`, then Hibernate tries to set `null`, it fails and exception is thrown:

```
[SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (MealIngredients.mealId may not be NULL)
```

Here are XML mappings:

```
<class name="restaurant.meal.Meal" table="Meals">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="id" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <!-- some other, simple properties -->

    <set name="ingredientsSet" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="mealId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="restaurant.meal.MealIngredient" />
    </set>
</class>

<class name="restaurant.meal.MealIngredient" table="MealIngredients">
    <composite-id name="id" class="restaurant.meal.MealIngredient$Id">
        <key-property name="ingredientId" />
        <key-property name="mealId" />
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="ingredient" class="restaurant.storage.Ingredient" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false">
        <column name="ingredientId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="meal" class="restaurant.meal.Meal" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false">
        <column name="mealId" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <!-- other properties -->
</class>
```

Yes, the relationship between `Meal` and `Ingredient` is *many-to-many* with join table `MealIngredient` (and yes, I have to map `MealIngredient` as well, because of additional columns in that table).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895126/rather-than-child-is-deleting-its-updating-when-parent-is-deleted) did not help me, neither did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957500/how-to-delete-child-in-hibernate-when-relationship-is-from-child-to-parent).

Edit:
Only inserting works with current mapping, update just generates another row in `MealIngredient` table.

---

**Edit 2:** `hashCode` and `equals` implementations:

**MealIngredient$Id**: (uses Apache `commons-lang` **EqualsBuilder** and **HashCodeBuilder**)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof Id))
        return false;

    Id other = (Id) o;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
               .append(this.getMealId(), other.getMealId())
               .append(this.getIngredientId(), other.getIngredientId())
               .isEquals();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
               .append(this.getMealId())
               .append(this.getIngredientId())
               .hashCode();
}
```

**MealIngredient**:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if(!(o instanceof MealIngredient))
        return false;

    MealIngredient other = (MealIngredient) o;
    return this.getId().equals(other.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return this.getId().hashCode();
}
```

I checked log and although I don't know what Hibernate does under the hood, but it does make the `insert` into `MealIngredient`:

```
15:42:53,122 TRACE IntegerType:172 - returning '5' as column: quantity3_
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        MealIngredients
        (quantity, ingredientId, mealId) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
15:42:53,131 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '16' to parameter: 1
15:42:53,131 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '5' to parameter: 2
15:42:53,131 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '1' to parameter: 3
```

And when I remove `MealIngredient` from `Meal.ingredientsSet`, Hibernate makes `update` and tries to set `mealId` to `null`:

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        MealIngredients 
    set
        quantity=? 
    where
        ingredientId=? 
        and mealId=?
15:48:57,529 TRACE IntegerType:126 - binding null to parameter: 1
15:48:57,529 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '1' to parameter: 2
15:48:57,531 TRACE IntegerType:133 - binding '1' to parameter: 3
15:48:57,535  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
15:48:57,535 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (MealIngredients.quantity may not be NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that Hibernate does not work well with composite primary keys. I had to add extra ID column into many-to-many join tables (like my `MealIngredient`) and work with that.

After I use extra ID as primary key, inserting/updating/deleting works as expected (even with `cascade` set to `delete-orphan`, cascade deleting works!).

I provide final mappings for entities `Meal` and `MealIngredient`, for future reference. I hope this will help others, when they stumble upon many-to-many relationships with additional properties/columns in join table.

```
<class name="restaurant.meal.Meal" table="Meals">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="id" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <!-- additional properties -->

    <set name="ingredientsSet" table="MealIngredients" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" inverse="true">
        <key update="true">
            <column name="mealId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="restaurant.meal.MealIngredient" />
    </set>
</class>
<class name="restaurant.meal.MealIngredient" table="MealIngredients">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="id" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="ingredient" column="ingredientId" not-null="true" class="restaurant.storage.Ingredient"  lazy="false" />
    <many-to-one name="meal" column="mealId" not-null="true" class="restaurant.meal.Meal" lazy="false" />

    <!-- additional properties -->
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the explanation you're looking for is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/).  Well, sort of.  Don't read his explanation, it confuses me.  His examples are excellent though.

So, anyways, I think you want to do one of the following:

`inverse=false` and remove the mealIngredient from your ingredients
   collection and then save the Meal

`inverse=true` and have to null the meal instance variable in MealIngredient and save the MealIngredient

***EDIT***: The issue with inserts instead of updates is probably due to the fact that you have not over-ridden hashcode and equals.  If you're using Eclipse, I believe it can do it for you, but you must tell it to use both properties of your composite key when it auto generates the methods.  Per [Hibernate documentation chapter 5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid):

> The persistent class must override equals() and hashCode() to
>   implement composite identifier equality. It must also implement
>   Serializable.

Comment: Well, the first option is what I'm looking for. I've tried many variations of the mappings (`inverse` with `true`/`false`, changed `cascade` options in `Meal` mapping as well as `MealIngredient`). None of that worked. Actually, now it does not even duplicate the record, it just does nothing (does not even update other properties in Meal). And regarding `equals()` and `hashCode()`, I _do_ have implemented them, and it still does not work.

Comment: @mnn Your `MealIngredient.equals()` and `MealIngredient.hacode()` methods shouldn't be using the Hibernate id for comparison.  Remember that when you first create it, if you're using an autogenerated key it's going to be `null` until you persist the object. More info [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) (I don't think that will fix your problem, but it will help later).

Comment: @mnn From the trace, it looks like Hibernate is trying to set your mealIngredient's quantity to `null` and that column has `not null`. Also, after sleeping on it, removing a `MealIngredient` from a `Meal` should probably result in the `MealIngredient` being `deleted()` since I bet `mealId` is `not null` as well.

Comment: But when I create MealIngredient, I create it with mealId already set. I don't put it into Meal.ingredientsSet until after ingredientId is correctly set to existing Ingredient. It's Meal and Ingredient that use autogenerated key, and they're not created in this case.

No, when I'm deleting `MealIngredient`, I just remove it from Meal.ingredientsSet, as you said I should (with `inverse=false`), and it is not removed from `MealIngredients` table.